# Unable to Get Chil Table List in Cascading Dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC- C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have three tables, `Student` table a CountryId, `Country` table have CityId in SQL Server. I am able to get all Country in my Create Student View Dropdown by JQuery Ajax but it is not possible get all the Cities in the same way. 
No city is loaded and the console is returning this error:

> jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 POST http://localhost:4007/Students/GetCityByCountries/2 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here in my `Students` controller code:

```
private StudentCountryFileDBEntities1 db = new StudentCountryFileDBEntities1();

public JsonResult GetCountries()
{
        return Json(db.Countries.Select(c => new
        {
            countryId=c.CountryId,
            countryName=c.CountryName
        }).ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetCityByCountries(int countryId)
{
        //var cityList = this.GetCitiesByConId(countryId);

        var cities = db.Cities.Where(c=>c.CountryId==countryId).Select(ct => new {
            cityId = ct.CityId,
            cityName = ct.CityName
        }).ToList();
        return Json(cities);

}
```

Here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="CountryId" class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Country</b></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="CountryId" name="CountryName"></select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <label for="CityId" class="control-label col-md-2"><b>City</b></label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="CityId" name="CityName"></select>
          @*@Html.DropDownList("City", ViewBag.Cities as SelectList, "Choose City", new { @class = "inputBox", @id = "CityId" })*@

          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
</div>
```

and the Jquery ajax code:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",

            url: "/Students/GetCountries",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                var countries = "<option value=''>Select Country</option>";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    countries += "<option value='" + data[i].countryId + "'>" + data[i].countryName + "</option>";
                }

                $('#CountryId').html(countries);
        }
});

$('#CountryId').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url: "/Students/GetCityByCountries/" + $('#CountryId').val(),
                data: "{id:$('#CountryId').val()}",
                success: function (res) {
                    var cities = "<option value=''>Select Cities</option>";
                    $('#CityId').html('');
                    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                        cities += "<option value='" + res[i].cityId + "'>" + res[i].cityName + "</option>";
                    }
                    $('#CityId').html(cities);
                }
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I also tried as like as country but the result is same....

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: 500. Internal server error. in the console

Comment: is it reaching controller (in debug mode, have a breakpoint in controller acton)? if its reaching, which line in the controller is throwing exception?

Comment: No, It was not reaching to the controller, but I got my solution bellow, A little thing was creating problem. Thank you for your cooperation. @sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example in jQuery. You must pass object to controller.

```
        var objParam = new Object();
        objParam.countryId = $('#CountryId').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Students/GetCityByCountries/",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(objParam),
            async: false,
            success: function (res) {

                $('#CountryId').empty();
                if (res.length > 0) {
                    $.each(res, function (key, Data) {
                        $('#CountryId').append($("<option></option>").val(Data.countryId).html(Data.countryName));
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#CountryId').empty();
                }

            },
            error: function (res) {
                responseData = null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ohf... Thank you so much @Adlorem. I just passed the objectParam and it worked. I didn't changed the whole at all, This little objectParam wasted my 4 days. Can you help me that, how can I learn these kind of things? A little problem costs a lot of time of mine and still I am confused to overcome it whenever I code.... Again thank you so much...

Comment: Glad I could help. Best way to learn except working with pros is to read other people code and search and ask questions on stackoverflow. Marking answers that work as accepted is also always welcome for ppl hunting for points ^^